# Создать метод возвращающий строку, в которой есть только по одному пробелу между словами

Tags: c#, строки

Написанный код не работает.

Решить пробую в LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    Debug.Assert(Foo("Is this a problem?") == "Is this a problem?", "Test # 1");
    Debug.Assert(Foo(" Is this a     problem?") == "Is this a problem?", "Test # 2");
    Debug.Assert(Foo(" Is  this a    problem?  ") == "Is this a problem?", "Test # 4");
    Debug.Assert(Foo(" Is   this  a  problem?  ") == "Is this a problem?", "Test # 5");
    Debug.Assert(Foo(" Is    this   a problem?  ") == "Is this a problem?", "Test # 6");
}
string Foo(string s)
{
     s = s.Replace(" ","");
     return s;
}
```

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Мой метод не работает

Comment: Ваш метод, фактически, удаляет все пробелы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два возможных варианта с регулярными выражениями (подозреваю, что первый вариант будет побыстрее, но не уверен), первый с `.Trim()`:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s{2,}", " ").Trim();
```

Второй без:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)", "");
```

Если нужна скорость, выражение, конечно, лучше скомпилировать заранее:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
s = regex.Replace(s, "");
```

Comment: Я даже не понимаю что там происходит Оо

Comment: @stasynyo, очевидно заменяются подряд идущие пробелы

Comment: выражения по разному работают с пробелами в начале и конце строки

Comment: @stasynyo, `\s` — любой пробел (обычный, табуляция, всё такое); `{2,}` — повтор предыдущего символа/группы два раза или больше. А вообще настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с [регулярными выражениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) поближе, очень удобно.

Comment: @SurfinBird спасибо большое, просто впервые вижу подобные конструкции `@"^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s`

Comment: @stasynyo, `|` — «или» (одно из трёх), `^\s+` — все пробелы в начале строки (`^` для начала), `\s+$` — все в конце, `\s+(?=\s)` — все группы пробелов (от одного и выше), после которых идёт пробел (после удаления останется лишь этот самый последующий пробел).

Answer (score 1):

То же самое можно сделать при помощи такого метода:

```
public static string Foo(string s)
{
    return String.Join(" ", s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

---

Если метод `Foo` вам нужен только для сравнения строк, и вам не принципиально использовать оператор `==`, то можно сделать это при помощи такого метода:

```
public static bool AreEqual(string s1, string s2)
{
    char[] space = { ' ' };
    return s1.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .SequenceEqual(s2.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Использование:

```
Debug.Assert(AreEqual(" Is    this   a problem?  ", "Is this a problem?"), "Test # 1");
```

Comment: а можно было сделать первой строке Join через пробел вернуть из функции и сравнивать по `==`

Comment: @Grundy Точно! Спасибо, сейчас добавлю.